# List all posts on Show view page - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list

I'd like to make a list of posts on the **app/views/posts/show.html.erb** page and sort each by id.

Similar to how all of the posts are listed on my **app/views/posts/index.html.erb** page using the code block below:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <%= image_tag post.img %>
  <h1><%= post.title %></h1>
  <p><%= post.content %></p>
  <br>
  <%= link_to 'Read More', post_path(post) %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

When I try to use the same each do method on the show page I get an error. But this is what I currently have (it only displays an img/link to the current post):

```
  <h1>Recent Posts</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <%= image_tag @post.img %>
      <h2>
        <%= link_to @post.title %>
      </h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index is for displaying all the items of x.

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

So what you are doing is taking all your posts, and putting them in an array called @posts. You can iterate or enumerate over those with .each do |x|. That means go through each object in the array and show the post image, title and content.

You didn't display your show, but typically a show looks like:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

So you are finding the post with :id and storing that data in @post. This is only 1 object, it's not an array. That's why your .each do |x| isn't working.

There is nothing stopping you from making

```
def show
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

But then you can't take advantage of rails shortcuts and are repeating yourself, which isn't good in programming. If you want two very distinct windows that use the same information, it's better to figure that out in html/css with a bit of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The show action of your `PostsController` is probably only setting up `@post`, and not `@posts`. You can't use `.each` with `@post` because it's an instance of `Post`, and not an array, or something that responds to `.each`. Look at how `@posts` is set up in the index action, and copy that to your show action.